# Select or Activate Function for opened Powerpoint Presentation

Tags: vba, object, select, powerpoint

Hello I am looking for the Syntax to Switch between two Presentations which are alreay open... something like select or activate...

```
Dim PPT As Object
Dim ppQuelle As Object
Dim ppZiel As Object




Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

With PPT
.Visible = True
.WindowState = 1
.Activate
End With

Set ppQuelle = PPT.Presentations.Open("I:\VS_52\520104\Vertriebsstories\Datensatz Markt\Fabian\Projekt\Produktpraesentation_Deka-DividendenStrategie_DE000DK2CDS0_PPT.pptx")
Set ppZiel = PPT.Presentations.Open("I:\VS_52\520104\Vertriebsstories\Datensatz Markt\Fabian\Projekt\Vorlage_Ergänzungspräsentation.pptx")



'Seite 13 bis 20 kopieren

For x = 13 To 20

With PPT
.ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Copy

'Seite 13 bis 20 einfügen


'.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Select
Application.WindowActivate ("I:\VS_52\520104\Vertriebsstories\Datensatz Markt\Fabian\Projekt\Vorlage_Ergänzungspräsentation.pptx")
.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
End With


Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Presentations("PRESENTATION_NAME").Windows(1).Activate
```

or

```
Presentations(PRESENTATION_INDEX).Windows(1).Activate
```

where PRESENTATION_INDEX is a Long